# Sum hours since a zero is entered

Tags: excel

I have written code for the 'Total Hrs Last Seven Days" - works fine.
In the "Total Hrs Since '0' Entered " column I want the formula to reset and sum from the "0"  upto the next 7 days  or until the next "0" is entered.

Col A = Date Col B = Hrs Cell C5 = Total Hrs last Seven Days Cell D5 = Total Hrs Since "0" Entered

[image]

My expected result for Cell D5 = 32

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual formula as text, and not just as an image? Thanks.

Comment: Can be in column B more than two zeros?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of `SUMIFS` and `MAXIFS`.

For the Last Seven Days calculation, I would use:

```
=SUMIFS( $B$5:$B$22, 
         $A$5:$A$22, "<=" & MAXIFS($A$5:$A$22, $B$5:$B$22,"<>"),
         $A$5:$A$22, ">"  & MAXIFS($A$5:$A$22, $B$5:$B$22,"<>")-7
       )
```

This sums all hours where the date is <= the latest date where the hours column is not blank AND the date is > that date-7.

The formula to calculate the last 7 days OR until the first 0, whichever comes first, is very similar. All we do is compare the date-7 to the latest date with 0 hours, and select the latest of the two with MAX:

```
=SUMIFS($B$5:$B$22,
        $A$5:$A$22, "<=" & MAXIFS( $A$5:$A$22, $B$5:$B$22, "<>"),
        $A$5:$A$22, ">"  & MAX( MAXIFS( $A$5:$A$22, $B$5:$B$22, "<>")-7, 
                                MAXIFS( $A$5:$A$22, $B$5:$B$22, 0)
                              )
       )
```

**EDIT: Formulas for older versions of Excel without `SUMIFS`**

The last seven days calculation was quite easy.
Just use `INDEX` with a simple `COUNT` to find how many Hrs cells have been completed. this gives use the "finish" index. We can then minus 6 from this count to get the "start index. And wrap the `INDEX`s in a `SUM`:

```
=SUM(
    INDEX($B$5:$B$22,COUNT($B$5:$B$22))
    :
    INDEX($B$5:$B$22,COUNT($B$5:$B$22)-6)
)
```

The Since "0" Entered formula is rather a lot more complicated:

```
=SUM(
    INDEX($B$5:$B$22,COUNT($B$5:$B$22))
    :
    INDEX($B$5:$B$22, 
        MAX(
            COUNT($B$5:$B$22)-6, 
            MATCH(
                AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$5:$A$22/($B$5:$B$22&""="0"),1),
                $A$5:$A$22 ,
                0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This works in the same way - by summing the range defined by two `INDEX`s. The "finish" index is also found in exactly the same way.

The "start" index is found by taking either, the last 7 days (as in the previous formula) OR the max date where the Hrs are zero. Which ever is greater. This is done using `MAX`.

The most difficult part is finding the maximum date which has zero hours, but is also not blank. We also need to allow for the possibility of there being multiple zeros in the last 7 days.

This can be done using `AGGREGATE` to find the date. Then using Match to turn that into the index that we need.

The only way I could get the aggregate to work (and not include blank cells as zero), was to turn the hours range into text and then compare that to the text "0":

```
$B$5:$B$22&""="0"
```

Comment: Would your code work on previous versions of Excel? I'm using Office 365 but we currently are using an earlier version at work. Thank you for you help. The code that you provided works perfectly!

Comment: No. Unfortunately, it wouldn't. You could replace the `MAXIFS` with `MAXIF`. But because there are multiple criteria in the `SUMIFS`, you couldn't replace that with `SUMIF`. If you need a formula compatible with earlier versions, I will update my answer when I have time.

Comment: @Gravitate there is no `MAXIF`  it was skipped and went straight to `MAXIFS`

Comment: @ScottCraner oh, really? Thank you. I did not know that. I always use the newer, plural functions, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, when you have it, to update the code. Thank you to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are formulas that will work with 2010 and later:

Last 7:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)-6))
```

Last since `0`:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B)):INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(B5:B22)/((B5:B22=0)*(B5:B22<>"")),1)))
```

[image]